# how to drawText transparent with background Path in Canvas Drawable?

Tags: android, drawable, battery

how to drawText transparent with background Path in Canvas Drawable?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkS41.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a transparent background with text on it like the first battery indicator?

If so create two Paint objects: one with alpha value (from 0 to 255) to draw the transparent background, the other one to draw your text.

Comment: how to? on picture, text is transparent